# filter a 6 tables Left join mysql Select (where?)

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have this 6 different tables with no common ID except a string field called  Player (or Name) in tables, and which is my common identifier.

My first table has the full table with names (players_list), a I start cascading  left joins to get a final table aggregating my customers data from each table (Deposits, etc)

here is the select

```
SELECT
    t1.Account,
    t2.OK,
    t5.Deposits,
    t4.GGR,
    t4.GGR - t3.Bonus AS NGR,
    t3.Bonus,
    t6.withdrawal
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `players_list`.`Account`
        FROM
            `players_list`
    ) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        online_players. NAME,
        'Online' AS OK
    FROM
        online_players
) t2 ON t1.Account = t2. NAME
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Player,
        Agent,
        sum(financial_view.Amount) AS Bonus
    FROM
        financial_view
    WHEREMethod LIKE '%BONUS%'
    GROUP BY
        Player
) AS t3 ON t1.Account = t3.Player
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Player,
        sum(result_account_short_date.Win) AS GGR
    FROM
        `result_account_short_date`
    WHERE
        datediff(
            Date_,
            DATE_FORMAT(
                (Now() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR),
                '%Y-%m-%d'
            )
        ) >= 0
    GROUP BY
        Player
) t4 ON t1.Account = t4.Player
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Player,
        sum(`financial_view`.`Amount`) AS Deposits
    FROM
        financial_view
    WHERE
        (
            Method NOT LIKE '%BONUS%'
            AND Type = 'Deposit'
        )

    GROUP BY
        Player
) t5 ON t1.Account = t5.Player
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Player,
        sum(financial_view.Amount) AS withdrawal
    FROM
        financial_view

    GROUP BY
        Player
) t6 ON t1.Account = t6.Player
ORDER BY
    t5.Deposits,
    t4.GGR DESC
```

The result below is fine. Nevertheless, I want to filter the players having at least one column without NULL. 
 In my case below,  Players : an, EST and munaaq should be filtered out.
How can I achieve this ? 
Thanks

```
    +-----------------+--------+----------+------+------+-------+------------+
    | Account         | OK     | Deposits | GGR  | NGR  | Bonus | withdrawal |
    +-----------------+--------+----------+------+------+-------+------------+
    | Djsta           | NULL   | NULL     | 200  | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
    | an              | NULL   | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
    | Ay              | Online | 25       | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
    | moa             | NULL   | 55       | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
    | Dhaq            | NULL   | NULL     | NULL | NULL | 50    | NULL       |
    | mohmoh          | NULL   | NULL     | 188  | NULL | NULL  | 199        |
    | EST             | NULL   | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
    | munaaq          | NULL   | NULL     | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL       |
```

Comment: HAVING COALESCE(ok,deposits,ggr,ngr,bonus,withdrawal) IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `WHERE` clause that contains all of your columns and ensures that at least one of them is a non-null value. For this you could use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT
    t1.Account,
    t2.OK,
    t5.Deposits,
    t4.GGR,
    t4.GGR - t3.Bonus AS NGR,
    t3.Bonus,
    t6.withdrawal
FROM
    (
    ... -- your code here
    )
WHERE 
    COALESCE(t2.OK,t5.Deposits,t4.GGR,t3.Bonus,t6.Withdrawal) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    t5.Deposits,
    t4.GGR DESC
```

Column `NGR` is not needed in the null-checking because it is being computed by values of two columns that are already being checked.

Column `Account` is provided in the first table that you are left joining to, thus it is not needed to check for its' content as well.

**Note:** If there are columns you know that are more likely to be not null than others, put them in front. This will speed the execution of the condition checking. `COALESCE` stops checking subsequent columns on first non-null value found.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It works as well! cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE COALESCE(t2.OK, 
               t5.Deposits,
               t4.GGR,
               t3.Bonus,
               t6.withdrawal) IS NOT NULL
```

[`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.